# Multiprocessing is stuck at the map function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am currently making a http request that has over 3,000,000 records by using the pagination method. Sometimes the call fails because of a 104 server error, so I retry and it works on the second or third time.

Because there are so many requests, I am using the multiprocess function in python to speed this along. I'm using a ubuntu 16 machine, python3.5 and an 8 core machine. The odd thing here is that all the files get written, and the process "Finishes" i.e reaches the end of the range (regardless of the size so 1 million or 2 million or 3 million) but it wont pass the pool line. So my tmux sessions just says "Working on date (lastrecordnumber)" I need that to occur so I can send an email to let me know the task has finished.

I've tried `pool.map()`; `pool.aysnc()`; `pool.map_async()`, they all seem to have the same issue.

```py
import http.client
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial


def get_raw_data(auth, url_conn, skip):
    headers = {'authorization': "Basic {}".format(auth)}
    sucess = None
    loop = 0
    while not sucess:
      try:
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url_conn)
        conn.request("GET", "SOME_API&$skip={}".format(skip), headers=headers)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()
        raw_data = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
        sucess = 'yes'
      except Exception as e:
        print('stuck in loop {} {} {}'.format(skip, loop, e))
        loop += 1

    with open('{}.json'.format(skip), 'w') as outfile:
          json.dump(raw_data, outfile)

 def process_skips(skip):            
    print('Working on date {}'.format(skip))    
    get_raw_data(skip)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("We started at {}".format(dt.datetime.now()))
    n = range(0,3597351,5000)
    n = list(n)  
    pool = Pool(8)
    pool.map_async(process_skips, n)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: So the pool runs properly and the map works because the process finishes but the pool is never closing?

Comment: It is not necessarily safe to `print` from a separate process. If you need logging you need a separate process with a logging queue.

Comment: Please check the formatting of your code. Not using standard (PEP8, I believe) formatting makes it hard to read for others and also, your indentation is faulty which is simply a Python error. That said, can't you simply mock the web requests, so that you get an actual [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Using pool as a context manager using `with` which takes care of closing/joining the processes and seems to be the preferred method in the docs.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("We started at {}".format(dt.datetime.now()))
    n = list(range(0,3597351,5000))
    with Pool(8) as pool:
        pool.map_async(process_skips, n)
```

If your main process is working and writing your file correctly, that should make your processes close out correctly.